# how is it tht my Arrays arent initialize?

Tags: mips

[image]

I just want to know, why my Arrays aren't initialized? can you please correct me.

Comment: I would suggest you to fix the spelling. Also avoid using images linked like that. Instead use code blocks and paste your code directly here. Most likely these two points will increase the interest toward your question. Good luck!

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Edit your question and add the code as text (properly formatted, e.g. using ctrl+k).